# Preserve plus signs from CGI input in Perl

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm working on a web application with several forms on which the user is expected to input data often containing spaces and/or plus signs.

The data is generally sent either through `GET` requests; or through `POST` requests with a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Content-Type header.

I have tried using either `Vars()` and `param` from Perl's `CGI` module, but both of these methods insist on converting the `+` signs into spaces.

Does the `CGI` module provide any mechanism to preserve the `+` signs; or should I ditch `CGI` and manually parse the `STDIN` input?

**Note**:
With the large amount of forms (over the hundred), and having the CGI pre-processing happening in a centralized utility library, I'm quite biased towards a server-side solution rather than a client-side approach (in other words, I'd rather deal with the problem once on the pre-processing code once than adding JS noise on hundreds of places).

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

**Example**:
As requested in the comments, here is a (simplified) sample of some code that triggers the issue.

**HTML**

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/some-script.pl">
    <input name="some_field" value="1 + 1 is 2">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Perl**

```
use CGI;
my $some_variable = CGI::param('some_field');
```

After submiting the form with the default value and running the server-side code, `$some_variable`'s value is `"1   1 is 2"` *(there are three spaces between the 1's, either the SO site or the browser may be collapsing them into a single space)*; the **desired outcome** would be to get the value `"1 + 1 is 2"` in that variable.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a minimal snippet of code that illustrates what steps are leading up to this problem.

Comment: You could simple encode the `+` sign as `%2B` before passing it to the CGI.

Comment: @dgw: Thanks for the suggestion, but could that be done on the server-side without having to pre-process the whole input? As mentioned in the question, a server-side solution is preferable over a client-side; and if I have to pre-process the whole input on the perl script, that wouldn't be much better than going all the way and manually parsing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Plus signs in CGI parameters mean spaces. That's in the CGI spec. Any HTTP client that sends you plus signs to mean anything else is broken. Any HTTP server that processes plus signs to mean anything else is broken.

So the problem is not in your CGI program (which is doing the right thing). The problem is in the HTTP client which is sending you plus signs intending them to be interpreted as plus signs. The correct way to sent a plus sign as a parameter in a CGI program is to encode it as %2B. That's the problem that you need to fix.

**Update:** I've run a simple test using Apache on Ubuntu.

My HTML file looked like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/param">
      <input name="some_field" value="1 + 1 is 2">
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Perl program looked like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use CGI qw[header param];

print header(-type => 'text/plain');

for (param) {
  say "$_ -> ", join ':', param($_);
}
```

When I visited the page and hit the 'submit' button, the browser went to the URL `http://localhost/cgi-bin/param?some_field=1+%2B+1+is+2&submit=Submit` and displayed the following:

```
some_field -> 1 + 1 is 2
submit -> Submit
```

This looks like the behaviour I expect to see. The browser correctly encodes the plus sign to %2B when sending it to the browser. Perl's CGI module decodes that value when I access it.

You need to track down why your browser (or whatever other client you're using to send these requests) isn't following the CGI spec.

Comment: Thanks! After some tracing, it seems that all the fields accross the app susceptible to include any non-usual characters are being pre-processed by some JS before being submitted. And that JS is, indeed, broken. I guess it will boil down to fixing (and, for sanity's sake, refactoring) those few hundred scripts.